# HyperSQL (HSQLDB) explicit shared (read) lock syntax

Tags: sql, database, transactions, locking, hsqldb

According to [HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#dac_jdbc_cursor_updatability), there are two select-for-updating directives:

- FOR UPDATE
- FOR READ ONLY

> If the SQL qualifier, FOR UPDATE is used, then all the updatable
>   columns of the result set become updatable.
>
> If a cursor is declared with FOR READ ONLY, then it is not updatable.
>
> In HSQLDB, if FOR READ ONLY or FOR UPDATE is not used then all the
>   updatable columns of the result set become updatable. This relaxes the
>   SQL standard rule that in this case limits updatability to only simply
>   updatable SELECT statements (where all columns are updatable).

If the `FOR UPDATE` takes an exclusive (write) lock, does the `FOR READ ONLY` directive take a shared (read) lock instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locks depend on the transaction model. The LOCKS and MVLOCKS models lock the table for write when FOR UPDATE is used. They lock the table for read when FOR READ ONLY is used. The MVCC model does not lock the table at all.

Comment: So there's no 'FOR SHARE' idiom for MVLOCKS. Thanks for clarifying it.